# Targeting specific elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I tried asking this before, but I guess I wasn't specific enough.  Suppose I have HTML code that looks like this.  How do I ONLY target the  tags within the the horizontalNAV using pure JavaScript?  Okay I know I could do this using jQuery like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#horizontalNAV li a').click(function(){
         //jQuery code here...
      });
   });
</script>
```

However I do NOT want a jQuery answer, because I want to know how you target **('#horizontalNAV li a')** using pure javaScript.

or you can tell me how to do it for the verticalNav portion, either way I'll get it, if I see an example or if its explained to me.  If I'm not mistaken you would have to use the document.querySelectorAll method, if so, how does that work in the above example.

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="horizontalNav">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#"></a>item1</li>
       <li><a href="#"></a>item2</li>
       <li><a href="#"></a>item3</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="sideBar">
      <div class="verticalNav">
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#"></a>item1</li>
           <li><a href="#"></a>item2</li>
           <li><a href="#"></a>item3</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial about JS and DOM: http://quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without jQuery it would look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

      var elems = document.querySelectorAll('#horizontalNav li a');

      for (var i = elems.length; i--;)
           elems[i].addEventListener("click", handler, false);

   }, false);

   function handler(event) {
       //javascript code here...

       this.style.color = 'red';
   }
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/9244y8jn/)

Comment: Appreciate the answer, just what I was looking for.  To expand on what you have, let say I wanted to do something simple like make the a tags that is targeted above change color or something dumb, how would I do that?  

Sorry if I'm pestering or dumb at this.

Things are so much simpler with jQuery ):

Comment: I've added something for that. Note that the ID's you're using doesn't match, it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

If *#horizontalNAV* is a UL or OL element, then it can only have LI element children so you can skip that part of the selector. The following doesn't use *querySelectorAll* so will work in browsers, that don't support it:

```
<script>

  window.onload = function() {
    var list = document.getElementById('#horizontalNAV');
    var links = list && list.getElementsByTagName(‘a’);

    if (links) {
      for (var i=0, iLen=links.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        links[i].onclick = listener;
      }
    }
  }

  function listener() {
     // do stuff
  }

</script>
```

If you want to include more than one listener for an event, you’ll need to use *addEventListener* or some other strategy instead of assigning the function directly to the element, but in most cases only one listener is required per event type and keeping things simple has its benefits.

The *listener* function is declared outside the function doing the assignment to avoid a closure and circular reference, so it should have less chance of creating a memory leak.

Comment: I understand, maybe li tags was a bad example.  I suppose in real life I would just use jQuery, I just don't want to be to dependent on it.  I'm a newbie at this stuff.

Comment: @dragonore—it's good to have an understanding of the underlying methods and how they work, that way you are able to evaluate when it's sensible to use jQuery and when not to.  jQuery is typically very much slower at doing DOM manipulation than plain JS. Learning to write efficient JS will also help you to write efficient jQuery and hopefully dispel the common belief that code is "better" simply by being shorter (often it's the other way around).